# Race Condition in CUDA programs

Tags: gpu, race-condition

I have two pieces of code. One written in C and the corresponding operation written in CUDA.
Please help me understand how `__syncthreads()` works in context of the following programs. As per my understanding, `__syncthreads()` ensures synchronization of threads limited to one block.

C program :

```
{
    for(i=1;i<10000;i++)
    {
        t=a[i]+b[i];
        a[i-1]=t;
    }
}
```

`

The equivalent CUDA program :
`

```
__global__ void kernel0(int *b, int *a, int *t, int N)
{
    int b0=blockIdx.x;
    int t0=threadIdx.x;
    int tid=b0*blockDim.x+t0;
    int private_t;
    if(tid<10000)
    {
        private_t=a[tid]+b[tid];
        if(tid>1)
            a[tid-1]=private_t;
        __syncthreads();
        if(tid==9999)
        *t=private_t;
    }
}
```

Kernel Dimensions:

```
dim3 k0_dimBlock(32);
dim3 k0_dimGrid(313);
kernel0 <<<k0_dimGrid, k0_dimBlock>>>
```

The surprising fact is output from C and CUDA program are identical. Given the nature of problem, which has dependency of a[] onto itself, a[i] is loaded by thrad-ID i and written to a[i-1] by the same thread. Now the same happens for thread-ID i-1. Had the problem size been lesser than 32, the output is obvious. But for a problem of size 10000 with 313 blocks and blocks, how does the dependency gets respected ?

Comment: Since thread indexing starts at 0, does it make sense `a[tid-1]`?

Comment: yes there will be correction, there will an if condition checking if the thread ID is >1.

Comment: So the `if` statement should check both then. I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding, **__syncthreads()** ensures synchronization of
>   threads limited to one block.

You're right. `__syncthreads()` is a synchronization barrier in the context of a block. Therefore, it is useful, for instance, when you must to ensure that all your data is updated before starting the next stage of your algorithm.

> Given the nature of problem, which has dependency of a[] onto itself,
>   a[i] is loaded by thread-ID i and written to a[i-1] by the same thread.

Just imagine the thread 2 reach the if statement, since it matches the condition it enters to the statement. Now that threads do the following:

```
private_t=a[2]+b[2];
a[1]=private_t;
```

Witch is equivalent to:

```
a[1]=a[2]+b[2];
```

As you pointed, it is data dependency on array `a`. Since you can't control the order of execution of the warps at some point you'll be using an updated version of the `a`array. In my mind, you need to add an extra `__syncthreads()` statement:

```
if( tid > 0 && tid<10000)
{
    private_t=a[tid]+b[tid];
    __syncthreads();
    a[tid-1]=private_t;
    __syncthreads();
    if(tid==9999)
    *t=private_t;
}
```

In this way, every thread gets its own version of `private_t` variable using the original array `a`, then the array is updated in parallel.

**About the *t value:**

If you're only looking at the value of `*t`, you'll not notice the effect of this random scheduling depending on the launching parameters, that's because the thread with `tid==9999` could be in the last warp along with the thread `tid==9998`. Since the two array positions needed to create the `private_t` value and you already had that synchronization barrier the answer should be right

Comment: I verified and the first `__syncthreads()` is redundant. I mean it is giving right results without it. I checked for different values of a[] and b[].

Comment: But the thing is, i am not happy that the kernel gave the right ouput. My understanding of the thread & block structure and the execution pattern in Streaming Multiprocessors(SM) is not finding logically coherent explanation for this program. As far i know, user have control only upto thread and block structure. Which block will go to which SM and further the ordering of blocks is not user-controlled.

Comment: Given a situation like this, a have created blocks of size=32 and #blocks in grid=313. Now imagine a situation like this : blockID=2 gets executed before blockID=1 and both gets scheduled to different SMs. So threadID=0, blockID=2 which has global threadID=64 updates value of a[63]. Next, when threadID=31, blockID=1 which has global threadID=63 now accesses global memory location a[63] and finds the new value of a[63]. This should result in destruction of dependencies. But somehow, the blockIDs are sequenced. Definitely, i am missing a subtle point here. Please help me find out.

Comment: What should be the right output of your kernel? Are you looking only the value of *t or the updated array?

Comment: @Sarkar, Your reasoning it is completely right. You cannot control nor infer the order of execution of the blocks (and therefore, of the threads). And that could yield the data conflict you pointed. The only thing you know is that warps are composed by 32 sequential indexed threads.

Comment: Updated array man! updated array should have incorrect values. Actually, i am experimenting on these CUDA execution pattern. And as per theory, the values should come incorrect, compared to serial execution on CPU. Where did i miss?